# Python3 unittest test seems to get tainted with value from previous test

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I've got a lot of good coverage so far with unittest, but this afternoon I encountered something that I have isolated as follows.  The simplest version of my class I was able to make is:

```
class Try:

    def __init__(self,xa=[]):
        self.XA = xa

    def getCount(self):
        return len(self.XA)

    @classmethod
    def newAfter(cls,arrayA):
        localo = cls()
        localo.pushX(arrayA[0])
        return localo

    def pushX(self,xFloat):
        self.XA.append(xFloat)
```

I have a trimmed down test set then as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# test_1_Try.py

import unittest

import Try as tr

class Test_Try(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_Constructs_with_no_argument(self):
        localo = tr.Try()
        self.assertIsInstance( localo, tr.Try )
        localo.pushX(5.333)

    def test_newAfter(self):
        localo = tr.Try.newAfter(["1.5"])
        self.assertEqual(1,localo.getCount())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    unittest.main()
```

That yields me a failing test with the failing diagnostics:

```
$ ./test_1_Try.py 
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_newAfter (__main__.Test_Try)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nsdd/shop/sames/statistics1v/bugdir/./test_1_Try.py", line 17, in test_newAfter
    self.assertEqual(1,localo.getCount())
AssertionError: 1 != 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s
```

But, if I take out the first test, and only run with the second, the test file passes.
Then, if I restore the tests together, but add the following assert first in the second test:
`self.assertEqual("1.5",localo.XA[0])`
That version of the tests result with the line:
`AssertionError: '1.5' != 5.333`

I am stumped.  I have the latter two tests in their own files, so I can post them, and their results in their entirety, if need be, but perhaps I am just too inexperienced in Python3 to know what I'm doing wrong.  Apologies.  As I said, unittest was working pretty well until now, and I've got some 48 tests working.  I hope I can keep using unittest.

Comment: Note that I have fixed this bug by making the __init__ argument assignment xa=None, then immeidiately checking for None, and assigning an empty array if so.  The feeling I get from all this is the kind of addressing error, perhaps in the C used to build unittest, but also possibly the python3 interpreter.  It really seems like something in these are just not adequately built.  I don't see anything irregular in my own coding.  If something obvious that I am doing exists, I would be happy to be yelled at it here, publicly, but I not getting it, and so far no response.

Comment: When you use a list (which is mutable) it will retain its state across your class instances which is why your instance of the class in the next test method has two values.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mess has pointed out, mutable default arguments are defined *once* at the point of function *definition*, not each time the function is called.

[You can read more about it here.](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

The article states:

> Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called (like it is in say, Ruby). This means that if you use a mutable default argument and mutate it, you will and have mutated that object for all future calls to the function as well.

Here is an example from the article on how you can avoid this:

```py
def append_to(element, to=None):
    if to is None:
        to = []
    to.append(element)
    return to
```

When you provide a value for the `to` argument, you should provide a list.

So in your example you could use the following:

```py
    def __init__(self,xa=None):
        self.XA = xa if xa is not None else []
```

That one-line if-else is known as a [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/expressions.html?highlight=ternary#conditional-expressions).

Comment: I just noticed I got "awards" for this post.  Perhaps that should be mitigated for the fact that after getting answered by one of the kind respondents above, I realized I saw a video about this argument stasis problem, and forgot about it.  I AM almost 65 years old, so thanks to whomever for the kindness, but I hope I can just contribute ethically, and I now convey my apologies for not recognizing this otherwise well known Python feature or deficit, which probably anyone spending at least 6 continuous months writing Python, would have it well remembered.